# Filter arrays corresponding to prefix and characters present in search string simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a string array like [Duabi -united arab emirates,Kastanea - greece , turin - italy],i need to filter corresponding to prefix and according to character in search string simultanously.
when i search for "D" it should show "Dubai - united arab emirates" and if i search 'united' it should show also show "Dubai - united arab" emirates.

Here is what i have done

```
       self.filteredArray = self.dataArray.filter({ (country) -> Bool in

            let countryText: NSString = country as NSString

                return countryText.hasPrefix(searchString) || countryText.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchString)

        })
```

I need high priority to prefix filtering ,if no result is present for prefix filtering it should check for containing string.

Comment: And what is your current result? What's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly do not need a bridge cast to `NSString` but `range(of`

```
self.filteredArray = self.dataArray.filter{ $0.range(of: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
```

It searches for the string regardless of *prefix* or *contains*, because `range(of` looks for the **first** occurrence of the string. Actually the `prefix` search in your code is redundant, too

Comment: using this code it will only check if the search string contains the value, i need filter according to the starting letter.

Comment: No. Once again: The code searches *for the first occurrence of the string* starting from the beginning.